# Is there a performance improvement with new border properties for ContentPresenter, Grid, and StackPanel that are introduced in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there a performance improvement with new border properties for ContentPresenter, Grid,and StackPanel are introduced in windows 10 uwp(universal apps), if yes how can we measure it? I tried tocheck the process memory after modifying the existing styles using the diagnostics tool in visual studio 2015, but it remains the same.The size of the control in memory remains the same, irrespective of, if you remove the extra border from visual tree or keep it. I observed this from the heap snapshot in the memory profiler of visual studio.

Comment: I would think the actual xaml parsing would be a small bit faster. Because there are less controls/tags in the xaml because of the property instead of real <Border> elements

Comment: Is there a way to measure it?

Comment: How to measure performance for apps, you could take a look at these resources, they discuss this in length... http://blog.kevindockx.com/post/NDC-2014-Windows-Store-Apps–Given-to-Fly-slides-code.aspx http://igrali.com/2015/11/19/tips-and-tricks-for-better-and-faster-windows-10-uwp-apps/

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted.  I don't see an accepted answer, so that is my guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to analyze the time spent by your application preparing UI frames (layout and render), , you can use  "the Application Timeline profiler"  in scenarios like Application Startup, Page Load and Windows resize.

Application Timeline is one of the tools you can start with the Debug / Start Diagnostics Tools Without Debugging command.

For detailed introduction about this tool, you can find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957934.aspx).